# Optaplanner and data base

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, optaplanner

I am currently coding with optaplanner and am using SQL Server for a database.

my system keeps throwing this  error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'stockLocations_StockLocationID'

I have checked and all my variable names against my database and they are all correct.

Here are my current classes:

shopify classes:

```
@PlanningEntity
@Entity
@DataSource("Shopify")
public class Shopify extends PanacheEntityBase{

@PlanningId
@Id
private Long ShopifyID;
private String CustomerName;
private String ProductSKU;

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "stocklocationRange")
@ManyToOne
private StockLocations stockLocations;

public Shopify(Long ShopifyID, String customerName, String productSKU) {
    this.ShopifyID = ShopifyID;
    this.CustomerName = customerName;
    this.ProductSKU = productSKU;
}

public Shopify(Long shopifyID, String customerName, String productSKU, StockLocations 
stockLocations) {
    ShopifyID = shopifyID;
    CustomerName = customerName;
    ProductSKU = productSKU;
    this.stockLocations = stockLocations;
}
```

stockLocation class:

```
@Entity
@DataSource("StockLocations")
public class StockLocations extends PanacheEntityBase {

@PlanningId
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long StockLocationID;
public String ProductSKU;
public String StockLocation;

public StockLocations(Long stockLocationID, String productSKU, String stock_Location) {
    this.StockLocationID = stockLocationID;
    ProductSKU = productSKU;
    StockLocation = stock_Location;
}

public StockLocations() {

}
```

allDetails class

```
@PlanningSolution
public class AllDetails {

@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
private List<Shopify> shopifyList;

@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "stocklocationRange")
private List<StockLocations> stockLocationsList;

@PlanningScore
private HardSoftScore score ;

private SolverStatus solverStatus;


public AllDetails(){

}

public AllDetails( List<StockLocations> stockLocationsList, List<Shopify> shopifyList) {
    this.stockLocationsList = stockLocationsList;
    this.shopifyList = shopifyList;
   // this.shopifyStockLocationsList = shopifyStockLocationsList;
}
```

and here is the main functionality javascript file used to display the data on the UI

```
function refreshAllDetails() {
    $.getJSON("allDetails", function (allDetails) {
        refreshSolvingButtons(allDetails.solverStatus != null && allDetails.solverStatus !== 
"NOT_SOLVING");
        $("#score").text("Score: " + (allDetails.score == null ? "?" : allDetails.score));

         const timeTableByRoom = $("#timeTableByRoom");
         timeTableByRoom.children().remove();
         const timeTableByTeacher = $("#timeTableByTeacher");
         timeTableByTeacher.children().remove();
         const timeTableByStudentGroup = $("#timeTableByStudentGroup");
         timeTableByStudentGroup.children().remove();
         const unassignedSKUs = $("#unassignedSKUs");
         unassignedSKUs.children().remove();

        //Picking Station Function
        const theadByRoom = $("<thead>").appendTo(timeTableByRoom);
        const headerRowByRoom = $("<tr>").appendTo(theadByRoom);
        headerRowByRoom.append($("<th>Picking Stations</th>"));
        $.each(allDetails.stockLocationsList, (index, stockLocations) => {
            headerRowByRoom
                .append($("<th/>")
                    .append($("<span/>").text(stockLocations.stockLocation))
                    .append($(`<button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 btn btn-light btn-sm p- 
1"/>`)
                    .append($(`<small class="fas fa-trash"/>`)
                    ).click(() => deleteRoom(stockLocations))));
    });

//IT WORKS!!! UNASSIGNED SKUS
    $.each(allDetails.shopifyList, (index, shopify) => {
        const color = pickColor(shopify.product_SKU)
        const lessonElementWithoutDelete = $(`<div class="card lesson" style="background- 
color: ${color}"/>`)
        .append($(`<div class="card-body p-2"/>`)
            .append($(`<h5 class="card-title mb-1"/>`).text(shopify.customerName))
            .append($(`<p class="card-text ml-2 mb-1"/>`)
                .append($(`<em/>`).text(`Product SKU: ${shopify.product_SKU}`)))
            .append($(`<small class="ml-2 mt-1 card-text text-muted align-bottom float
            right"/>`).text(shopify.id)))
            //append($(`<p class="card-text ml-2"/>`).text(shopify.billing_Name_Added)));
    const lessonElement = lessonElementWithoutDelete.clone();
    lessonElement.find(".card-body").prepend(
        $(`<button type="button" class="ml-2 btn btn-light btn-sm p-1 float-right"/>`)
            .append($(`<small class="fas fa-trash"/>`)
            ).click(() => deleteLesson(shopify))
    )
    if (Shopify.stockLocations == null) {
        unassignedSKUs.append(lessonElement);
    }
    
 });

 });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This a Hibernate-JPA and JDBC issue that isn't related to OptaPlanner.

> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'stockLocations_StockLocationID'"

That means that this Hibernate-JPA configuration:

```
@Entity ...
public class StockLocations extends PanacheEntityBase {

...
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long StockLocationID;
```

doesn't match the database table schema. The SQL table for that entity has no SQL column with the name SotckLocationID. Probably this is just the tip of the iceberg.

In optaplanner's quarkus-school-timetabling quickstart, we use

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
```

to destroy the entire database and model it 100% like the model, every time it starts up. That's great for development as the model changes (obviously very bad for production).

Comment: My database contains the field and the naming in the code is correct as well I can't seem to figure out why it keeps throwing that error but I will try your quarkus code thank you!

Comment: are there any optaplanner examples that use actual databases?

Comment: the quarkus-school-timetabling quickstart uses an in memory H2 database. It can be easily switch to postgresql, mysql, mariadb, etc. For inspiration how, go to quarkus-quickstarts and look for the hibernate-jpa or panache examples that use postgresql.